# Flask doing calculations returns wrong values

Tags: python, math

I am trying to calculate 3 things, profit, total cost and the amount.

A user puts in the amount of coins he/she wants to spend. Each product has a buy price and a selling price, and I need to get, well profit, total cost, and amount.

I am doing that with this piece of code right here:

```
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bFlipper():
    product_name = []
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2').json()
    for x in productNames:
        product_name.append(f["products"][x]["product_id"])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userInput = request.form['coins'] # UserInput
        userInput = int(userInput)
        sell = [product['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
                for product in f['products'].values() if product['sell_summary']]

        buy = [product['buy_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
               for product in f['products'].values() if product['buy_summary']]

        amount = []
        for x in range(len(buy)):
            amount.append(userInput * buy[x]) # This here calculates the amount user can buy

        total = []
        for x in range(len(buy)):
            total.append(amount[x] * buy[x])# This here calculates the total cost

        profit = []
        for x in range(len(buy)): 
            sell_profit = amount[x] * sell[x]
            buy_profit = amount[x] * sell[x]
            total_profit = sell_profit - buy_profit
            profit.append(total_profit) # This here calculates the profit user will make
        return render_template("flipper.html", userInput=userInput, product_name=product_name, profit=profit, amount=amount, total=total, sell=sell, buy=buy)
    else:
        return render_template("flipper.html", product_name=product_name)
```

The issue is that it returns the wrong values, for example:

User puts in `'123321'` coins. The program will then do:

```
123321 / buy = amount # how many of product x he/she can buy with 123321 coins.
amount * buy = total cost # the total cost
total cost(sell) - total cost(buy) # how much profit it will make
```

Currently, it returns the wrong values. `123321 / 4.6 = 26808 (the amount) # 4.6` is an example of a product buy price

shows in the browser as: `727594`. Which is a bit wrong! How do I fix this?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer with a [mcve] that shows input going in, and bad output going out.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase the question! @Carcigenicate

Comment: This is just a math error somewhere (I can't really follow the question) not a flask error

Comment: I seem to have figured it out, the only issue I have right now is for "total cost", made "amount" to work, for some reason I had to do "userInput / sell[x]" instead of buy? Anyways, thanks for the help! @roganjosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as roganjosh said, there is nothing to do with flask. The answer is just to debug the program and you will probably find your math mistake. Maybe open a test file and see if your math is correct there.

Comment: I seem to have figured it out, the only issue I have right now is for "total cost", made "amount" to work, for some reason I had to do "userInput / sell[x]" instead of buy? Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: @SimonSjöö As I said in my answer debug the program(if you don't know how just print it at the states you need (less recommended)) and check the line of the problem. If it helped you accept the question.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't print it out for some reason (on the main project), did it on a separate project, and saw that for some reason the 'sell' and 'buy' variables were carrying the opposite values. A bit strange.. because it doesn't to that on the website... But again, thanks for the help! I should have expected something like that!